# Why Http Post in Orchard Core asp net core Web App returns bad request

Tags: api, asp.net-core, orchardcore

I'm using Orchard core in asp net core web app project. I have a controller with two simple get and post Apis. As I'm using OrchardCore the Startup.cs file has different config and I dont use services.AddControllers() in configureServices.
Every thing is fine untill I'm using HttpGet. But when I want to have an Api with HttpPost postMan says badRequest. So I Added services.AddControllers() in Startup.cs and the post Api was fine in post Man but the orchard project says I have multipe Endpoints.
I used services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson(), and every thing was fine but the admin page didn't load and had error as below:

> InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' was not found. The
> following locations were searched:
> /Areas/OrchardCore.AdminDashboard/Views/Dashboard/Index.cshtml
> /Areas/OrchardCore.AdminDashboard/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
> /Views/Shared/Index.cshtml /Pages/Shared/Index.cshtml

I wold appreciate it if you can help me how to call Post Api.
here is my code:

```
[HttpPost("post")]
    public Task<string> post()
    {
        return Task.FromResult("hiPost");
    }

    [HttpGet("get")]
    public Task<string> get()
    {
        return Task.FromResult("hiGet");
    }
```

and this is my startup.cs

```
 public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            //services.AddControllers();
            services.AddOrchardCms();
            services.AddMediatR(typeof(SelectedWebSiteBlogQueryHandler).Assembly);
            services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));
            services.AddCors();
            services.AddMvc().AddNewtonsoftJson();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            app.UseCors(o => o.AllowAnyOrigin().AllowAnyHeader().AllowAnyMethod());
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseOrchardCore();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are probably missing an `IgnoreAntiForgeryToken` attribute on your controller.

`AntiForgery` is enabled by default by `OrchardCore`

For an `ApiController` in `OrchardCore` I would expect to see the controller decorated as follows.

```
[ApiController]
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = "Api"), IgnoreAntiforgeryToken, AllowAnonymous]
```

However this depends if you are using the `OpenId` module to authenticate with, or simply need to post to a normal controller, without an `AuthenticationScheme`

Depending on what you are actually posting from in real life, it may be better to supply an anti forgery token as part of your post.